# Use IPython magic functions in ipdb shell

Tags: python, debugging, ipython

When debugging Python script using `ipdb my_script.py`, I want to use IPython magic functions like `%paste`, `%cd` in `ipdb` debug session shell. Is is possible and how?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to the [ipdb Github repo](https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb/issues/33) magic IPython functions are not available. Fortunately, the [IPython debugger](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/core/debugger.py#L521) provides a couple of clues of how to get this functionality without launching a separate IPython shell.

Here is what I did to run `%cpaste`:

```
ipdb> from IPython import get_ipython
ipdb> shell = get_ipython()
ipdb> shell.find_line_magic('cpaste')()
Pasting code; enter '--' alone on the line to stop or use Ctrl-D.
:for i in range(0,5):
:       print i
:--
0
1
2
3
4
```

This way, you can step through your code and have access to all the IPython magic functions via the method `find_line_magic(your_magic_function)`.

Comment: Can you pass the context (e.g. local variables)  of ipdb to `cpaste`?

Answer (score 19):

You can open a IPython shell inside a stack, just like pdb does. Do the following:

- Import embed() from IPython, and put it inside your code.
- Run the script

Example:

```
from IPython import embed

def some_func():
    i = 0
    embed()
    return 0
```

**In Python shell**:

```
>>> te.func()

IPython 1.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
(...)

In [1]: %whos

Variable   Type    Data/Info
i          int     0

In [2]:
```

Was that what you were looking for?

Comment: I'd like to use the magic functions without importing any IPython functions in my code.

Comment: why? is it just a matter of personal convenience?

Comment: @flebool, it would be quite convenient to access the magic functions  wherever and whenever my program is stopped (suspended) by the debugger without having to code breakpoints in my program.

Comment: The provided answer, though usefully provides a way to allow magic functions to be used via the `ipython` shell but not in an `ipdb` shell unfortunately.

Comment: This approach is much easier. You can also combine these two lines together  `from IPython import embed; embed(); import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` in your code, then now you can use all the magic functions from IPython.

Comment: @LinDong this is great, but debugger commands like `c` or `s` are not available in ipython shell

Comment: this doesn't allow you to perform operations like `continue`, `next`, `jump`, and changing frames. is there a reason why magic functions can't be added to `ipdb` directly ?

Comment: @Curious, you just have to exit the ipython interpretor to get back to `ipdb` to be able to do that