# Running IPython magics in ipdb

Tags: ipython, ipdb

Can I use IPython magics such as  `%paste` and `%cd` in ipdb?. Is there any way to have ipdb interpret these magics in the command line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use IPython magic functions in ipdb shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184487/use-ipython-magic-functions-in-ipdb-shell)