# Pass field value to custom layout.Field

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I am defining a custom layout object:

```
Field('slider', template="custom-slider.html")
```

as seen in the [documentation](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/layouts.html#universal-layout-objects):

My custom-slider is:

```
<div class="slider slider-green" data-prefix="&euro; " data-postfix=",-" data-min="0" data-max="1800" data-value="223"></div>
```

But I want to parametrize those values. How can I do this? How can I pass values to the template when using a layout.Field? How can I get min/max value from the related Formfield?

```
slider = forms.IntegerField(label="slider", min_value=3, max_value=50)
```

If I understand this correctly, the custom-slider.html is a fully functional django template. What is the context? Does it have access to the related form field? How? I am unable to find an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is `field` context variable passed to that template which contains the `FormField` object. So you should be able to do this:

```
<div class="slider slider-green" data-prefix="&euro; " data-postfix=",-"
data-min="{{ field.field.min_value }}" data-max="{{ field.field.max_value }}"
data-value="{{ field.value }}"></div>
```

The reason you have to do `field.field` is that the `field` that is passed to the template is a [`BoundField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.BoundField) object, rather than the `IntegerField` that you defined in your form class. *That* object [is stored in `BoundField.field`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/boundfield.py#L27) - hence `field.field`.

The `BoundField` has a [`value()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/boundfield.py#L126) method which is why `field.value` works.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not working for me. Those values are blank in my template, except the {{field.value}}, which has the right value. How can I access the context to see by myself what values/objects are available? I would like to take a look at the `field` object in the context. Do you have any trick for that? I have django-debug-toolbar installed, but I am not able  to see the `field` object in the context there. Is it possible to drop into an iPython shell when rendering a specific template (a kind of template breakpoint)?

Comment: Put [`{% debug %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#debug) in the top of your template - that will dump the context for you to inspect.

Comment: I have done that, and also used django-debug-toolbar, and browsed through the crispy-form implementation, and used a templatetag to start a debugger inside the template (both pdb and ipdb), and browsed the django.template.context.RequestContex implementation, and ... but I simply can not find how to list all available properties of the field context object. `max_value` and `min_value` are definitely not available, but `value` is. How do you know what objects/properties should be available to a template?

Comment: If you can find the `field` object, then check `type(field)` to make sure it is an `IntegerField` like you are expecting and `dir(field)` to see what properties and methods it exposes. What does that give you?

Comment: I have added a detailed answer of my debugging process, which is maybe helpful for others. Don't ask we why, but the max/min values are in `{{field.field.max_value}}` (that is, a *double* field specifier). And the value is in `{{field.value}}`, as you correctly stated. Just for that I upvote you, but please correct the other specifiers to avoid confussion.

Comment: I figured out why this is... will post an explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to put here my current progress, even though this is not yet solved (but I am getting closer I hope). I have tried the following to solve this:

- used [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar): great, but the context dump is not readable for complex templates. It is just a huge `__repr__` dump, not browsable at all, and lacking information (since the `__repr__`s by necessity are shortened)
- used [`{% debug %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#debug) in the template: even worse. I can not read that. It helps maybe for small templates, but if you have a form with 5 fields, and three other template tags, good luck with reading that.
- [used a `pdb` breakpoint](https://opensourcehacker.com/2013/05/16/putting-breakpoints-to-html-templates-in-python/) to access the context. `pdb` gives you an interactive interface to the context, but it is not easy to use.
- used an `ipdb` breakpoint. This is a little better, but it is not [possible to use magic functions](https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb/issues/33) (even though are listed).
- used an [embedded ipython shell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18808166/647991). This is a **game changer**. Suddenly you are possible to easily browse context, related functions, code, automatically pretty print everything, use tab completion, ...

My `templatetags` for this have been (file `templatetags/debug.py`):

```
from django.template import Library, Node


register = Library()


class PdbNode(Node):

    def render(self, context):
        import pdb as pdb_module
        pdb_module.set_trace()
        return ''


class IPdbNode(Node):

    def render(self, context):
        import ipdb as ipdb_module
        ipdb_module.set_trace()
        return ''


class EmbedIPythonNode(Node):

    def render(self, context):
        from IPython import embed
        embed()
        return ''


@register.tag
def pdb(parser, token):
    return PdbNode()


@register.tag
def ipdb(parser, token):
    return IPdbNode()


@register.tag
def ipython(parser, token):
    return EmbedIPythonNode()
```

And you can use it in the template like:

```
{% load debug %}
{% ipython %}
{% pdb %}
{% ipdb %}

<row>
  <div class="col-lg-6""></div>
  <div class="col-lg-6"">
    <div class="slider {{field.extra_class}}" data-prefix="{{field.prefix}}" data-postfix="{{field.postfix}}" data-min="{{widget.min}}" data-max="{{widget.max}}" data-value="{{field.value}}"></div>
  </div>
</row>
```

(You need to `pip install` `ipython` and `ipdb`)

This is an example session:

```
In [15]: dir(context.dicts[5]['field'])
Out[15]: 
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dict__',
 '__doc__',
 '__format__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__getitem__',
 '__hash__',
 '__html__',
 '__init__',
 '__iter__',
 '__len__',
 '__module__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__',
 '__unicode__',
 '__weakref__',
 '_initial_value',
 'as_hidden',
 'as_text',
 'as_textarea',
 'as_widget',
 'auto_id',
 'css_classes',
 'data',
 'errors',
 'field',
 'form',
 'help_text',
 'html_initial_id',
 'html_initial_name',
 'html_name',
 'id_for_label',
 'is_hidden',
 'label',
 'label_tag',
 'name',
 'value']
```

And thanks to the `ipython` shell, I was able to find that the max value is in `{{field.field.max_value}}`. No idea why a double field specifier is needed, but it works.