# Silently install and enable nbextensions

Tags: jupyter

When I have extensions enabled,  I get a tremendous amount of output when I do the following:

```
$ jupyter contrib nbextension install --sys-prefix  --log-level=50
$ jupyter nbextension install --py full_width --sys-prefix  --log-level=50
... various extensions ...


| b'Enabling: jupyter_nbextensions_configurator\n- Writing config:
```

This output buffers very slowly, like tens of minutes and often crashes my editor.  I'd just rather silence all output.  I figured the log_level command would do that, but it did not seem to.

How can I disable all output from jupyter_nbextensions?

Answer (score 0):

Read this:

[%%capture](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#cellmagic-capture)

Try

```
%%capture
!jupyter contrib nbextension install --sys-prefix  --log-level=50
!jupyter nbextension install --py full_width --sys-prefix  --log-level=50
```

Comment: I'm not clear how to call `%%capture` from the shell.  It would make sense from within the notebook.

Comment: [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361206/how-to-run-an-ipython-magic-from-a-script-or-timing-a-python-script)                                                               
                                                                                                                             [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16184487/use-ipython-magic-functions-in-ipdb-shell)